# Complex Analysis Definition

Tags: complex-numbers, definition

Link to textbook: [https://math.unice.fr/~nivoche/pdf/Brown-Churchill-Complex%20Variables%20and%20Application%208th%20edition.pdf](https://math.unice.fr/%7Enivoche/pdf/Brown-Churchill-Complex%20Variables%20and%20Application%208th%20edition.pdf)

[image: 1]

For statement 3, I am not sure why the RHS is equivalent to the LHS. What would $-arg(z_{2})$ indicate in this instance if

$z_{2}^{-1} = \frac{1}{r_2}e^{-i\theta_2}$

I think $-\arg(z_{2})$ is:

$-r_2e^{-i\theta_2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $\operatorname{arg}(z)$ denotes an argument of $z$. So, if$$z_2=r_2e^{i\theta_2},\tag1$$you can write $\theta_2=\operatorname{arg}(z_2)$ since $\theta_2$ is an argument of $z_2$. On the other hand, it follows from $(1)$ that $\frac1{z_2}=\frac1{r_2}e^{-i\theta_2}$ and that therefore $-\theta_2$ is an argument of $\frac1{z_2}$; in other words, $-\theta_2=\operatorname{arg}\left(\frac1{z_2}\right)$.